# Make a buffer active by its number

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, buffers, terminal, terminal-buffer

I'm configuring a terminal buffer and now I have the following problem. I have only one terminal buffer and I need to make it active by its number to avoid lots of `CTRL-w j/k/l` clicks.

Here is what I tried:

1. Given `vim` opened I typed `:bot term` to create a new terminal buffer:

[image]

Here we have a terminal buffer opened on the bottom.

2. I go to the top buffer and try to make terminal focused by its buffer number to type some commands (this particular case is simple, but in general navigation might be complicated).

I type the following commands right in vim one by one

```
:let g:tn = bufnr("$")
:echo g:tn "prints 2
:b 2
```

And here is where the problem comes. Instead of just activating the terminal I got 2 synchronized terminal buffers:

[image]

So the top buffer became "a mirror" of the terminal buffer with the number 2.

Is there a way to fix it? So just activate a terminal to type some more commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Make a buffer active by its number

You can combine `win_gotoid()` & `win_findbuf()` to accomplish this:

```
:call win_gotoid(get(win_findbuf(g:tn), 0))
```

But we can do better for terminal like things by improving a few things:

- Automatically set our variable on `TerminalOpen` autocmd
- Provide methods to send text to the terminal
- Provide a command to jump to the term or open it

Add the following to your `vimrc` or better yet `~/.vim/packages/bundle/start/send-to-term/plugin/send-to-term.vim`:

```
augroup sent_to_term
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufWinEnter,TerminalOpen * if &buftype ==# 'terminal' |
        \   let t:sent_to_term_bufnr = +expand('<abuf>') |
        \ endif
augroup END

function! s:term_op(type, ...)
  let [sel, rv, rt] = [&selection, @@, getregtype('"')]
  let &selection = "inclusive"

  if a:0 
    silent exe "normal! `<" . a:type . "`>y"
  elseif a:type == 'line'
    silent exe "normal! '[V']y"
  elseif a:type == 'block'
    silent exe "normal! `[\<C-V>`]y"
  else
    silent exe "normal! `[v`]y"
  endif

  call s:send_to_term(@@)

  let &selection = sel
  call setreg('"', rv, rt)
endfunction

function! s:get_current_term(...)
  if a:0
    let bufnr = bufnr(a:1)
  else
    let bufnr = get(t:, 'sent_to_term_bufnr', 0)
  endif
  if bufnr > 0 && bufexists(bufnr) && getbufvar(bufnr, '&buftype') ==# 'terminal'
    return bufnr
  else
    let v:errmsg = 'No Terminal'
    throw "SendToTerm: " . v:errmsg
  endif
endfunction

function! s:send_to_term(keys, ...)
  let restore = bufnr('%')
  try
    let bufnr = call(function('s:get_current_term'), a:000)
    silent execute 'b ' . bufnr
    let lnum = line('$')
    normal! G$mp
    let keys = substitute(a:keys, '\n$', '', '')
    call term_sendkeys(bufnr, keys . "\<cr>")
    echo "Terminal: Sent " . len(keys) . " chars -> " . bufname(bufnr)
    call setpos("'[", [bufnr, count(keys, "\n") + 1 + lnum, 1, 1])
  catch /^SendToTerm:/
    echohl ErrorMsg 
    echo "Error: " . v:errmsg
    echohl None
  finally
    silent execute 'b ' . restore
  endtry
endfunction

function! s:goto_term(...)
  try
    let bufnr = call(function('s:get_current_term'), a:000)
    let winid = get(win_findbuf(bufnr), 0)
    if winid > 0
      call win_gotoid(winid)
    else
      execute 'sb ' . bufnr
    endif
  catch /^SendToTerm:/
    echohl ErrorMsg 
    echo "Error: " . v:errmsg
    echohl None
  endtry
endfunction

command! -range -bar -nargs=? -complete=buffer SendToTerm call s:send_to_term(join(getline(<line1>, <line2>), "\n"), <f-args>)
command! -bar GotoTerm call s:goto_term()
nmap <script> <Plug>(send-to-term-line) :<c-u>SendToTerm<cr>
nmap <script> <Plug>(send-to-term) :<c-u>set opfunc=<SID>term_op<cr>g@
xmap <script> <Plug>(send-to-term) :<c-u>call <SID>term_op(visualmode(), 1)<cr>
```

With this you can use `:GotoTerm` to jump to the last opened terminal buffer and use `:SendToTerm` with a range to send a range of lines to the terminal buffer. I also provided `<Plug>` mappings to send motions and visually selected text to the terminal.

```
nmap yrr <Plug>(send-to-term-line)
nmap yr <Plug>(send-to-term)
xmap R <Plug>(send-to-term)
```

Comment: Instead of adding autocmd on terminal open I currently store a buffer id of the just opened terminal into a global variable. Is there any problem with such an approach?

Comment: @St.Antario, nothing wrong with saving it manually. You probably don’t want all the other code I provided. Hopefully someone will find it useful. I would recommend wrapping up `win_gotoid()` and `win_findbuf()` into a command or mapping though

Answer (score 3):

> So the top buffer became "a mirror" of the terminal buffer with the number 2.

Your problem is that you confuse "buffer" and "window". Those "rectangles" you see are called "windows", while their contents are called "buffers".

So the command `:b 2` says "I want a buffer number two to be shown in the current window". And that's not what you really wanted.

> So just activate a terminal to type some more commands?

You have to find a terminal *window* and then make it active.

```
for w in getwininfo()
    if w.terminal
        call win_gotoid(w.winid)
        break
    endif
endfor
```

Comment: That exe could be an exe wincmd instead

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `win_gotoid()` is even better, so I'll stick to it instead.

Comment: Nice; wonder if that's new

Comment: @D.BenKnoble `win_gotoid()` was introduced in Vim 7.4.1557 and since `:terminal` is the big feature of Vim 8.1 it is safe to use in this case